# How do you re-render DatePicker with updated defaultValue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datepicker, material-ui

I'm using DatePicker in the following scenario:

1. Render the form that used DatePicker
2. on componentDidMount, fetch form's saved information (if it was saved previously)
3. set DatePicker's prop `defaultValue` from `undefined` to the fetched value

Seems pretty simple. But, since DatePicker's behaviour is to render `defaultValue` only on the first render, it obviously is empty when the value is fetched (second render).

The other two options i see:

1. Have a controlled component - manipulate value manually (provide it when its fetched, and then change it when onChange fires)
2. Render DatePicker only if there's nothing to fetch (new form) or once the data has been fetched and ready to be populated.

Any thoughts on what the best approach would be to accomplish this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

UPDATE: I no longer use React so don't have the inclination to retest this but I strongly suspect that this no longer works.

#### Prior answer

Rather than populate the `defaultDate` prop, hook the `value` prop to whatever you want it set to. Using this approach, you'd also want to wire up an `onChange` handler. It would look something like this:

```
onChange(event, newValue) {
  this.setState({myDate: newValue})
},
render() {
  return (
    ...
    <DatePicker value={this.state.myDate} onChange={this.onChangeHandler}>
    ...
  )
},
```

Alternatively, you could use the two-way binding functionality using React's `LinkedStateMixin` and the `DatePicker`'s `valueLink` prop.

Comment: thanks, i ended up going with the option 2 (rendering component once i have the fetched default value) rather than implementing a controlled component (less code rewriting) but ill take a look at this `LinkedStateMixin` sounds interesting. thanks!

Comment: I suspect this no longer works.